# Javascript validation condition fails

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The below java script condition works in two condition but one of the condition is not working properly.

Page has a field which allow user to enter either without wildcard or with wild card with two characters For eg: PA% or PAGTHYUR

If the user enter PAGTHYUR in the Search Field still the else condition alert is calling "There is delay processing times for broad wildcard searches" instead of directly submit the "searchType".

How to avoid the else alert if the user enter direct value(for eg:PAGTHYUR)

My Script is as below:

```
if(manufNo!="") {
  var strLen = manuNo;
  var wild = "%";
  if(strLen.indexOf(wild) != -1 && strLen.indexOf(wild) < 2) {
    alert("Enter atleast two characters before wildcard");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert ("There is delay processing times for broad wildcard searches"); 
  }
  searchType = "manufNo";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must provide a working sample to be able to pinpoint the problem, including the working js, and html.

Comment: Oh dear, what a terrible formatting, please pay attention next time to presentation

Comment: @emporio, your username is "emporio" and you do not have his picture as avatar. I'm disappointed.

Comment: sure will do next time sorry

Comment: what do you mean by "his picture"?

Comment: Emporio's picture. It's a character and i thought your nickname was based on him. Lol.

Comment: Some high-tech internet humor going on right here, I will contemplate changing my picture. Thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra `else if` in case there is no wildcard, you just gotta figure out what you want to happen in that case:

```
if(manufNo!=""){
  var strLen = manuNo;
  var wild = "%";
  if (strLen.indexOf(wild) === -1) {
     //code for what happens when there is no wildcard
     // potentially nothing?
  } else if (strLen.indexOf(wild) < 2){
    //well place wildcard
    alert("Enter atleast two characters before wildcard");
    return false;
  } else {
    //badly placed wildcard
    alert ("There is delay processing times for broad wildcard searches"); 
  }
  searchType = "manufNo";
}
```

Comment: When I entered with out wild card it is showing "Enter atleast two characters before wildcard" not calling searchtype to  submit .Please help